# Swift 4: Sort UITableViewCells by RSSI value

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

I am searching for BLE devices and want to have the one with best signal strength displayed at the top.

Is there a way to sort the UITableViewCells by the RSSI value, so the one with the best signal strength(e.g. "-39") is displayed at the top?

I have search for at solution and tried a couple of thing and this was my idea, but it does not work:

```
func startScan() {

    peripherialNames = [ ]

    RSSIs = [ ]

    RSSIs.sort(by: { $0.intValue < $1.intValue})

    connectTableView.reloadData()

    centralManager?.stopScan()

    centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)

}
```

I tried to sort the array of RSSIs but that does not alter the sorting, or lack thereof, in the app.

I tried using .intValue because of the RSSIs being NSNumbers.

Pic of the app in action as it is now:
[Found BLE devices and their RSSI values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9KMm.jpg)

Thanks!

-Thomas

Comment: I can't quite follow the logic of your code. Where do you add the rssis to the array?  That is where you need to sort the array and reload the table

Comment: Let me guess after seeing this: `peripherialNames = [ ]; RSSIs = [ ]`, you hope that `RSSIs[0]` correspond to the RSSI of `peripherialNames[0]`, right? Just don't use multiple array for holding values that are supposed to be synced. You are in that issue because you are sorting the RSSI, but not modifying the `peripherialsNames`. So if you load the tableView with the names it won't work. Last, check after `RSSIs.sort(by: { $0.intValue < $1.intValue})` if it's really sorted, it might be your sort which is wrong.

Comment: @Larme I have now added a picture of the app in use. As it shows it does not sort the RSSI values. But yes your are correct, the point is also that the peripheralNames and RSSIs should go together

Comment: Use a struct/class, let's name it `class Peripheral { let peripheral: CBPeripheral; var rssi: Number; var name: String = { return peripheral.name }}`, use only an array for it, and update the RSSI when needed. Then sort according to the RSSI.